# Periodic lag spike on wifi connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have an intermittent hiccup wifi connection problem on my PC. This is the ping result from the PC to the wireless router:

```
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2795ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2807ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2779ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2782ms TTL=64
```

Connection from another laptop to the same wireless router is fine.

I have tried swapping the wireless adapter, but the problem persists on this PC.

Both wireless adapters work fine on the other laptop.

I tried connecting the wifi adapter to two other USB ports, the hiccup persists.

I have used a wifi analyzer on my phone near the wifi adapter. Signal strength is about -60, using channel 11. Not overlapping with other wifis.

Any other things I should check? Would appreciate some help troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: Is the driver up to date?

Comment: Also check the firmware for updates on your wireless router.

Comment: Drivers are up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some other things like running Fiddler to detect traffic (nothing suspicious), buying USB extension cable so I can move the WiFi adapter to different places to rule out interference, and uninstalling and installing drivers, I discovered that it was Firefox.

It just so happened that I have command prompt open running ping when I opened Firefox, and the spikes started appearing every 5 seconds. I closed Firefox and the spikes went away.

I tried running Fiddler while opening Firefox, but didn't detect any traffic when the spike happened.

I tried running Firefox in safe mode (shift click to run). Spike still happened.

I tried to refresh Firefox (shift click Firefox in start menu, select 'refresh Firefox'), and looks like this one solved the issue. Firefox doesn't cause spikes anymore.

Firefox version 108.0.1.